# Unknown Attachment Type

Tags: c#, botframework, bots

I deployed the Bot Application to azure which is working in "Test in Web Chat" and also in Local Bot Emulator. But throwing some warning in Microsoft Teams i.e. Unknown attachment type .

It is basically the searching bot app which will ask for the file name and return the attachment which include content type , Name and Content URL of the document.

Please help on this.

Comment: `ask for the file name and return the attachment which include content type , Name and Content URL of the document` Please share the code that you are using to send attachment.

Answer (score 2):

> throwing some warning in Microsoft Teams i.e. Unknown attachment type.

I create a sample to send attachment from bot to user, and configure my bot to connect to Microsoft Teams channel. If I send something like pdf file, same issue appears.

```
var replymes = context.MakeMessage();

replymes.Attachments.Add(new Attachment()
{
    ContentUrl = "https://xxxxxxx/xxx.pdf",
    ContentType = "application/pdf",
    Name = "test.pdf"
});
```

***Not work in Microsoft Teams:***

[image]

***And warning in channel issues:***

[image]

***Work fine in web chat:***

[image]

I suspect that the `ContentType` of the file that you want to send as an attachment is not support yet in Microsoft Teams channel, so you get “**Unknown attachment type**” warning.

Comment: [Same issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+Unknown+attachment+type%2Cpdf) might appear in another channels.

Comment: To add to this, some channels do not allow bots to send certain file types.  For example, Skype does not let bots send pdf's which would lead me to believe all Microsoft internal channels probably follow suit.

Comment: Is this issue resolved. I facing exact same issue here.